# How to get index from Arraylist which contains string

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Below is my model:

```
public class Products {

    String date = "", item = "";

    public Products () {

    }
    public Products (String date String item ) {
        this.date = date 
        this.item  = item ;
    }

    public String getdate() {
        return date 
    }

    public void setdate (String date) {
        this.date = date 
    }

    public String getitem () {
        return item 
    }

    public void setitem (String item) {
        this.item  = item 
    }
}
```

And below code for defined the Arralist:

```
  private ArrayList<TasksCharts> mArrayList;
```

and i have data in ArrayList:

```
position 0 -> date - "2016-10-02" , item = "pens"
position 1 -> date - "2016-10-03" , item = "xyz"
position 2 -> date - "2016-10-03" , item = "fts"
```

Now i want the position of ArraList whose contain "pens" . So for that i have eritten below code:

```
 if (containsSubString(mArrayList, "pens")) {
   int listIndex = getItemPos("pens");
  } 


private int getItemPos(String item) {
        return mArrayList.indexOf(item);
    }
```

When i runt this it will give me `-1` index for item `pens`.

How can i get the index of particular item ?

Comment: where have you defined `containsSubString`?

Answer (score 2):

Does a `TasksCharts` Object containing `pens` equal a String Object containing `pens`?

Unless you have overriden the equals method I would say "no".

I would recommend that you use a Map instead or you will have to loop through looking for a `TasksCharts` Object containing `pens`

Answer (score 2):

You can run a for loop to get job done .

```
 private int getItempos(ArrayList<TasksCharts> mArrayList, String str)
{
  for(int i=0;i<mArrayList.size();i++)
  {
     if(mArrayList.get(i).item.indexOf(str)!=-1)
     {
         return i;
     }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

you should do sth like this :

```
         private int getItemPos(String key ,  String item) {
            int i = 0;
            for (i=0; i<mArrayList.size(); i++)
            {
                if(mArrayList.get(i).get(key).equalsIgnoreCase(item))
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

and call

> int x = getItemPos("item" , "pen");

Answer (score 1):

I have simply added products in the same ArrayList and then used for-loop to find that product position.

```
ArrayList<Products> mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

Products products1 = new Products("2016-10-05", "Pens");
Products products2 = new Products("2016-10-04", "Pencil");
Products products3 = new Products("2016-10-03", "Book");
Products products4 = new Products("2016-10-02", "Dairy");


mArrayList.add(products1);
mArrayList.add(products2);
mArrayList.add(products3);
mArrayList.add(products4);

for (Products products : mArrayList) {
    if (products.getitem().equals("Pens")) {
        Log.d("Position", mArrayList.indexOf(products) + "");
    }

}
```

This will give Output as

```
D/Position: 0
```